# CUDALink is not initialized

Tags: cudalink, system

I've upgraded to Mathematica 9.0 on Ubuntu 12.04 with the latest Nvidia driver (304.64).
I load CUDA by using, as usual, `` Needs["CUDALink`"] ``.

`CUDAQ[]` reports True.
`CUDAInformation[]` reports:

> ```
> {1 -> {"Name" -> "GeForce GT 330M", "Clock Rate" -> 1265000, 
>    "Compute Capabilities" -> 1.2, "GPU Overlap" -> 1, 
>    "Maximum Block Dimensions" -> {512, 512, 64}, 
>    "Maximum Grid Dimensions" -> {65535, 65535, 1}, 
>    "Maximum Threads Per Block" -> 512, 
>    "Maximum Shared Memory Per Block" -> 16384, 
>    "Total Constant Memory" -> 65536, "Warp Size" -> 32, 
>    "Maximum Pitch" -> 2147483647, 
>    "Maximum Registers Per Block" -> 16384, "Texture Alignment" -> 256,
>     "Multiprocessor Count" -> 6, "Core Count" -> 48, 
>    "Execution Timeout" -> 1, "Integrated" -> False, 
>    "Can Map Host Memory" -> True, "Compute Mode" -> "Default", 
>    "Texture1D Width" -> 8192, "Texture2D Width" -> 65536, 
>    "Texture2D Height" -> 32768, "Texture3D Width" -> 2048, 
>    "Texture3D Height" -> 2048, "Texture3D Depth" -> 2048, 
>    "Texture2D Array Width" -> 8192, "Texture2D Array Height" -> 8192, 
>    "Texture2D Array Slices" -> 512, "Surface Alignment" -> 256, 
>    "Concurrent Kernels" -> False, "ECC Enabled" -> False, 
>    "TCC Enabled" -> False, "Total Memory" -> 1073414144}}
> ```

It seems that everything works. But if try to perform the following:

```
randM = RandomReal[1, {1000, 1000}];
CUDADot[randM, randM];
```

I get:

> CUDADot::notinit: CUDALink is not initialized.

What does it mean? I already tryied googling looking for the error message... nothing found.
Thanks in advice to whom can shed light.

Comment: I formatted your question.  Please read this: [editing help.](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help)

Comment: Since you mention that you just upgraded to v9, it may be worth running `CUDAResourcesInstall[Update->True]`.  I had problems with CUDA in 9 because it tried to use the v8 resources.  But in that case not even CUDAQ[] gave True.  It's probably not the cause of the problem, but it's worth a try.  Be prepared for a longish download though.

Comment: I've tried CUDAResourcesInstall[Update->True] and CUDAResourcesUninstall[]. CUDADot is still not working.

Comment: Same for me on Fedora 18; everything in `SystemInformation[]` -> `Links` -> `CUDA` seems fine.

Comment: everything in SystemInformation[] -> Links -> CUDA is fine for me, too. Still CUDADot is not working. Could I ask you which is your Nvidia driver version (mine 304.64)?

Comment: [Link to MathGroup version of the same question](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/l4-b7p4NfC0/discussion)

Comment: @HopfMap Same, 304.64.

Comment: Same problem in Fedora 16 with Mathematica 9.
CUDAQ and CUDAInformation works ok. thanks

Comment: @b.gatessucks You mean it doesn't work for you either?  So is there anyone at all for whom CUDALink works on Linux?

Comment: Is this 9.0.0 or 9.0.1?

Comment: @Szabolcs Yes I mean it doesn't work for me but all the "CudaChecks" seem ok. It was working on the same machine, previous Fedora release but can't remember which driver version.

Comment: @HopfMap It seems you're not alone with this issue, so you could consider asking support@wolfram.com.  If you manage to work out a solution, please come back and post an answer.  Make sure you point them to this comment thread to show that several people are having the same problem on Linux.

Comment: I have v9.0.1 and am running Ubuntu (precise) with driver 295.41 for a GTX560M. Not having any problem with `CUDADot`; gives a 3x speedup.

Comment: @Xerxes, which version of `gcc` did you use to compile the NVIDIA drivers and the CUDA Toolkit? Are you using CUDA 5.0?

Comment: I contacted Wolfram support. Apparently several other users are affected by this bug, and the developers are looking into it. They will contact me as soon as they have a solution/workaround. I will post as soon as I hear back from them.

Comment: See this answer [link](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/23075/how-to-troubleshoot-cudalink/23421#23421). Although it's not a solution that can work for everyone (laptops generally cannot change graphics card), it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Applied this sample code on a notebook freshly initialized and kernel quit off and on

```
     Unprotect["`*"]
    ClearAll["`*"];
    Needs["CUDALink`"]
    Needs["OpenCLLink`"]
    Needs["SymbolicC`"]
    OpenCLQ[]
    CUDAResourcesUninstall[]
```

On a separate cell write

```
    CCompilers[]
CUDADriverVersion[]
CUDAResourcesInstall[]
$CUDADeviceCount
SystemInformation[]
```

Look very the CCompilers returns. There is an issue with the GCC compiler and shall see if you might be required to back to an older version or upgrade it.  Post the results of the code sample provided.